# Navigation Drawer Dynamic Menu Item Id issue

Tags: android, dynamic, navigation, navigation-drawer

I trying to set dynamic menu items in the navigation drawer. I succeeded. But how to call intent passing with some data when someone clicks on that menu item?

Here is my code to set a dynamic menu item

```
private void addMenuItemInNavMenuDrawer() {

    NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
    for (int i = 0; i < catTitleList.size(); i++) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Integer.parseInt(catIdList.get(i)), Menu.NONE, catTitleList.get(i));
    }

    navView.invalidate();
}
```

How can I call Intent from `onNavigationItemSelected`(MenuItem item)?

here is the onNavigationItemSelected

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    NavigationView nv = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    Menu m = nv.getMenu();
    int id = item.getItemId();

    int catId = Integer.parseInt(catIdList.get(0));
    if (id == R.id.nav_ebook) {

        if (!m.findItem(catId).isVisible()) {
            m.findItem(catId).setVisible(true);

        } else if (m.findItem(catId).isVisible()) {

            m.findItem(catId).setVisible(false);

        }
     } else (id == CatId) {
        String tag = viewAll1.getTag().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AllSubCategory.class);
        i.putExtra("ID", tag);
        startActivity(i);
     }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You'd do it exactly the same way you would with resource-defined menu items. What specific problems are you having?

Comment: How dynamic is your catTitleList? How do you know what intent will go with what item from that list?

Comment: @MikeM. The concern is, I am getting dynamic category title in catTitleList(). As I have to set the same menu as my category title and Id is. I am setting dynamic title and ID for menu as you can see in  addMenuItemInNavMenuDrawer(). Problem is how to perform onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) for dynamic manu having dynamic id.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding the issue correctly, but you don't necessarily need to use your category ID for the menu item ID. You could simply use the index as the menu ID – i.e., `menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, ...);` – then in `onNavigationItemSelected()`, you can use `item.getItemId()` to grab the actual category ID and its title from the lists. Apart from that, I'd mention that it would probably be easier to handle these things if you were to create, e.g., a `Category` class with ID and title fields, and keep a single `List<Category>`. That's not really relevant to your current issue, though